# Is this design pattern code smell? How to achieve this using DI?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I'm writing a WPF application using MVVM.  My ViewModels are quite large and have a lot of logic associated with them (filtering, searching, writing to the database, etc), so I've decided to try to separate out the logic of the ViewModels to a "Presenter" class like is used in MVP.

So, my basic setup is this:

```
public class FooViewModel : ViewModelBase, IFooViewModel
{
     private IFooPresenter presenter;
     private ObservableCollection<FooModel> fooCollection;

     public FooViewModel()
     {
           presenter = FooPresenter(this);
     }

     public ObservableCollection<FooModel> FooCollection
     {
           get { return fooCollection; }
           set
             {
                  fooCollection = value;
                  OnPropertyChanged("FooCollection");
             }
     }

     public void FooCommandMethod(object obj)
     {
           presenter.DoStuff();
     }  
}

public class FooPresenter : IFooPresenter
{
    private IFooViewModel viewModel;

    public FooPresenter(IFooViewModel viewModel)
    {
        this.viewModel = viewModel;   
    }

    public void DoStuff()
    {
         viewModel.FooCollection.Add(new FooModel());

         //etc etc, make whatever ViewModel updates are needed
    }
}
```

I feel like it is bad practice to have this circular dependency (View Model depends on Presenter and Presenter depends on View Model).  These classes could be combined into one large ViewModel class, but I do like how clean this approach keeps my View Models, all that they do is hold commands that call presenter functions and hold the Model/collections of the Model.  I also dislike the dependency of the ViewModel on the concrete implementation of the Presenter.  One approach I have toyed with is using a Service Locator type class, so it would look like this:

```
     public FooViewModel()
     {
           presenter = PresenterLocator.GetPresenter<IFooPresenter>(this);
     }
```

What I would prefer, though, is to use Constructor Dependency Injection to inject the controller when I create the ViewModel.  The problem with this is that this creates a circular dependency in the constructors of the ViewModels and Presenters, which causes my application to crash when I attempt to achieve this using Unity.  It ends up looking like this:

```
     public FooViewModel(IFooPresenter presenter)
     {
           this.presenter = presenterl
     }
```

And

```
     public FooPresenter(IFooViewModel viewModel(
     {
          this.viewModel = viewModel;
     }
```

So, my concern is that my design approach is inherently flawed due to this.  Nevertheless, I really like how clean it keeps my ViewModels and separates them from Business Logic.  Is there a better way I could be designing this?  Is there any way I can use DI to achieve this?  Or by doing that am I essentially trying to force a DI container to act as a Service Locator?

Comment: I don't smell anything.

Comment: It is perfectly OK to have a circular reference there... In former days this was a problem, because instances could live forever and memory went short. With your second part you could think about the factory pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would not call this a "presenter". This introduces an unwanted confusion, in fact your presenter doesn't present anything, it is just an extracted bit of code from a large view model. Have you considered calling it just "a service"? A `SearchService` for example?

Another question is: does such service always depend on a view model? Or rather, could it depend on lower layers (unit of works/repos for example) or other services? Note that because your service depends on a view model and you pass a view model directly there, you loose a control of what happens to the view model inside a service. Your `DoStuff` method is a perfect example, it does something to a view model, alters its state. Instead, you could have

```
public class FooViewModel : ViewModelBase, IFooViewModel
{
  private IFooService service;
  private ObservableCollection<FooModel> fooCollection;

  public FooViewModel()
  {
     service = FooService(this);
  }

  public void FooCommandMethod(object obj)
  {
     // the responsibility on consuming service outcome is still here!
     this.FooCollection.Add( service.CreateNewModel() );
  }  
}

public class FooService : IFooService
{
  // constructor parameter not needed now
  public FooService()
  {
    this.viewModel = viewModel;   
  }

  public FooModel CreateModel()
  {
     return ...;
  }
}
```

If you still insist however on having a circular dependency, make it so that one of the two has a parameterless constructor and a property injector:

```
public class FooViewModel : IFooViewModel
{
    private IFooService _service;
    public FooViewModel( IFooService service )
    {
        this._service = service;
        this._service.Model = this;
    }
}

public class FooService : IFooService
{
    public IFooViewModel Model { get; set; }
}
```

This way Unity asked for a `IFooViewModel` will resolve a parameterless `IFooService` and then execute the constructor that sets the cycle for both parties.

Comment: Thanks.  My initial design was what you are suggesting - not to have the service depend on the ViewModel.  However, the ViewModels ended up requiring some complex filtering logic, i.e. CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(collection).Filter =Etc, so to put this in the service I needed direct access to the ViewModel.